# Find desktop files in wubi disk

Tags: 13.04, wubi

Short question: where is the ~/Desktop/ files in the root.disk (wubi) ?

**Details:**

Hello, I've been using wubi in windows 7 x32 for a while and then had to change my main operating system to windows 8 x64.
Note: the wubi was x64.

So I formatted my OS partition (the wubi was installed in the other one) and then I couldn't open ubuntu anymore. And then found out that it was possible to nagivate through .disk files in this website, and installed the ext2explore and then found all documents that were in ~/Documents and ~/Downloads.

*However, when I opened the **~/Desktop** the folder was **empty**, and I am sure most of my files was/is there.*

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're booting from a live CD (which it sounds like you are), then `~/Desktop` is the `/home/ubuntu/Desktop` folder on the live CD and it is empty.

If you mounted the Wubi `root.disk` file, then you need to reference it directly from the mountpoint. e.g. if you ran

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win
sudo mount -o loop /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /mnt
```

Then you'll find your Desktop folder under `/mnt/home/<your_username>/Desktop` (replacing `<your_username>`with your user name from the Wubi install), not under `~/Desktop`.

Comment: No, I am not using a livecd. I was using a tool for windows that can open the wubi disks. (it might even be an error of this program).

But anyway thanks for answering, Actually I found a workaround:
I moved the disks files to another folder, reinstalled wubi, replaced the new created files with the older ones and everything was there as I left. But I still don't understand where is the "/Desktop" in wubi's disk. I say that because, as I could reach both Documents and Dowloads. I would expect that a "$/Documents/ cd ../Desktop" would send me to the actual desktop that I was using...

Comment: Yes `cd ../Desktop` from the `~/Documents` directory should get you to the desktop - as does `cd ~/Desktop`

Comment: but when I tried it, the "*/Documents" were the same as I was using in the disk and the "*/../Desktop" was empty.  

=/

Comment: Hmm I don't know what's up. With Unity, Ubuntu has moved away from the "store files on the desktop" model, but whether that explains how a bunch went missing - I don't know. I suppose you could try using `testdisk` to recover deleted files?